# T-sql use local variable like a as clause

Tags: t-sql, local-variables

I want to use that i declare local variable like a **as clause**,
for example

i get last year and current year

```
declare @lastYear varchar(4)=datepart(YEAR,DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()));
declare @currentYear varchar(4)=datepart(YEAR,DATEADD(year,0,GETDATE()));
```

and

i want to use like a above,

> ```
> select a.totalCountLy  as @lastYear,
> a.totalCountLy as @currentYear from TableName as a (nolock
> ```

And result is like

```
2011          2012
------------------
1000          5000
400           1000
```

Any suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the only way.  The fact that you want to do this makes me think you should review what you are doing.

Comment: @DanAndrews,i thought,may be another way.Thanks your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, using dynamic SQL?

```
declare @lastYear varchar(4)=datepart(YEAR,DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()));

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
    N'select a.total as [' + convert(nvarchar(24), @lastYear) + N'] from TableName as a'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: thanks @Phill,this way is usuable,but i thought-( or curious :) ),maybe i use a in normal t-sql query.

Comment: @engcmreng: dynamic sql is the only way to do what you're asking.